# Is there any way to have ER diagram with relationship connectors for the MySQL database schema?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

In MySql, I have to generate/draw an ER diagram which having the tables and their relationships (the primary key & foreign key). I tried it with MySQL Workbench by the **Reverse Engineering** option but it just having tables without any foreign keys connectors among the tables.

Please help me to draw foreign key connectors on ER diagram from the MySQL Schema.

Thanks.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-relationship-tools.html  use this doc. I used the same @himmat

Comment: Do you have foreign key relationships built within your database schema? If yes, I am surprised that workbench didn't pull relationships. https://medium.com/@tushar0618/how-to-create-er-diagram-of-a-database-in-mysql-workbench-209fbf63fd03 is a blog that could potentially help.